# Статическая переменная count не уменьшается

Tags: java

Никак не получается сделать так, чтоб уменьшалось количество котов. В консоли выдаёт постоянно -overbignumber.
Count нужно добавить именно в метод meow. В getStatus сказали не добавлять.

````
import javax.sound.midi.Soundbank;

public class Cat
{
    private double originWeight;
    private double weight;

    private double minWeight;
    private double maxWeight;
    private double eatenFood = 0;
    private static int count = 0;

    public Cat()
    {
        count++;
        weight = 1500.0 + 3000.0 * Math.random();
        originWeight = weight;
        minWeight = 1000.0;
        maxWeight = 9000.0;

    }

    public void meow()
    {
        weight = weight - 1;
        if (weight < minWeight || weight > maxWeight);
        count = count - 1;
    }

    public void feed(double amount)
    {
        weight = weight + amount;
        eatenFood += amount;
        eatenFood++;
        if (weight < minWeight || weight > maxWeight);
        count = count - 1;
    }

    public double getEatenFood()
    {
        return eatenFood;
    }


    public void drink(Double amount)
    {
        if (weight < minWeight || weight > maxWeight);
        count = count - 1;
        weight = weight + amount;
    }

    public double getWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }

    public String getStatus()
    {
        if(weight < minWeight) {
            return "Dead";
        }
        else if(weight > maxWeight) {
            return "Exploded";
        }
        else if(weight > originWeight) {
            return "Sleeping";
        }
        else {
            return "Playing";
        }
    }
    // сходить в туалет!
    public void pee () {

        weight = weight - 100.0;
        System.out.println("I do it!");
        if (weight < minWeight || weight > maxWeight);
        count = count - 1;
    }
    public static int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }
}
//// Другой класс
public class Loader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            System.out.println("Cats count:" + Cat.getCount());
            Cat murka = new Cat();
            Cat vasya = new Cat();
            Cat rings = new Cat();
            Cat masha = new Cat();
            Cat mashka = new Cat();
            System.out.println("Cats count" + Cat.getCount());
            while (murka.getWeight() > 1000)
                murka.meow();
            while (masha.getWeight() > 1000)
                masha.meow();
            vasya.feed(vasya.getWeight()/0.1);
            rings.feed(rings.getWeight()/0.1);
            System.out.println("Murka status:" + murka.getStatus());
            System.out.println("Vasya status:" + vasya.getStatus());
            System.out.println("Masha status:" + masha.getStatus());
            System.out.println("Rings status:" + rings.getStatus());
            System.out.println("Cats count:" + Cat.getCount());
        }
    }
}```
Сделав count в getStatus всегда выходило нужное количество котов, когда они умирали/взрывались. Сейчас же, если убрать 
           while (masha.getWeight() > 1000)
                masha.meow();
то тоже выходит нужное количество котов. Но с этим методом вечно минус тысяча котов.
````

Comment: `if (weight < minWeight || weight > maxWeight);` в первый раз вижу if, который ничего не делает

Comment: Ну точно....
Всё, получилось! 
Я тупой:)

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот примерно как-то так...

```
if (weight < minWeight || weight > maxWeight){

count = count - 1;

}
```